# over ssh, After some minutes Gtk-WARNING

Tags: ssh, x11, gtk

I connect to a server over ssh with

```
ssh -CX server
```

ok, And I launch remote graphical apps, ok.
But after some minutes I get

```
Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display
```

And I have to reset the ssh connection.

Added some outputs

```
$ echo $DISPLAY; echo $XAUTHORITY
localhost:11.0

$ xauth list
machine/unix:12
machine/unix:10
machine/unix:11
```

Comment: What application is producing this message? What do you mean by “I have to reset the ssh connection”: do you mean you can't start new X applications, or that all X applications crash, or that the whole connection including the command line is terminated (with what error message if any)?

Comment: I can't start new X applications

Comment: Please post the output of `echo $DISPLAY; echo $XAUTHORITY` in a working connection and in a failed connection. Also, the output of `xauth list | awk '{print $1}'` (anonymize machine names if you like).

Comment: I added to output to question

Comment: Is that in a working or failed connection? And please post the other one as well, the point is to compare the two.

Comment: *coughacceptratecough*

Comment: Does it happen after it's idle for a certain period of time? Have you tried replicating it with -vvv turned on in your ssh session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this to my `.ssh/config`

```
host myHost                                                           
user myUser
port 22
hostname ipHost
ForwardX11 yes
Compression yes
ForwardX11Trusted yes
```